# Single vote reversed by serial vote reversal script?

Tags: support, voting-correction

I just noticed that my reputation history shows a voting reversal event of -10 rep happened a week ago.

[image: Rep history entry showing a voting reversal of -10 rep]

I know what vote reversals are, but there's something that's bugging me about this: how did the *serial* voting detector find a *single* fraudulent vote? I mean, how does it decide whether a single vote is fraud or just a plain vote? Or, if it found multiple related votes, why did it reverse only one of them?

Comment: One way this could've happened (if I understand correctly) is if the detected "serial voting" occurred across multiple accounts, and yours just happened to receive only a single one of those corrected votes.

Comment: @zcoop98 That seems to make sense, I didn't think of multiple-account voting frauds...

Comment: @Zoe I agree that there's almost certainly a duplicate for this lying around, but isn't a post about a "massive reversal" the _exact_ opposite of this particular case? Lol

Comment: @zcoop98 It's a dupe because it's the same cause. Or rather, same ring, without going into more detail because I have no idea how much we can actually say about this complete mess

Comment: Out of all hundreds of users affected by this, you seem to have been affected the least. Nonetheless, this was serial voting. You just got a single vote out of it all.

Comment: It wasn't the detector that found or reversed this. It wasn't an automated reversal. You are correct that the automated process would not reverse a single vote. This was, instead, a manual reversal by staff, based on evidence that staff & mods can see site-wide, but cannot share with you for confidentiality reasons.